# Could utility fog be used to build a planet?

Tags: planets, engineering, religion, terraforming, gods

I am considering the plausibility of creating a Project involving “Gods”. These are super intelligent beings composed entirely of utility fog; clouds of nanotechnological components capable of assuming any shape, which are therefore omnipotent and omniscient over a given area.

These Gods use their powers to assemble entire planets from space dust and asteroids, apparently at a whim. They then populate these planets with genetically engineered life forms of their own devising, often imposing twisted but undeniably true religions about themselves on the populace.

What I want to know is, is it possible for utility fog to assemble such a planet, and how long, if so, would this take?

Comment: Be cautious with the use of omnipotent and omniscient words; Without context if you say they're really omnipotent the answer is trivial (->yes). But if we take some common conceptions of nanofogs the answers are often bit more nuanced. Can you tell more exactly what they're capable of?

Comment: The substance they are made of can become solid or gaseous in seconds. The foglets are made from aluminium oxide, and can replicate themselves using aluminium from their environment. Naturally, a god grows in power and influence as it grows in volume

Comment: Dang! I clicked add comment. Anyway, continuing, they can reproduce by separating parts of themselves which creates a new entity. These “godlings” are only the size of your average cumulus cloud, but the largest gods (the planet builders) are big enough to envelop worlds.

Comment: Utility fog is already so far into handwavium science that I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be able to build a planet.

Comment: Not again! They are also powered by heat.

Comment: VTC OB (a) How on earth can we know what "utility fog" can or cannot do? Every aspect of its fictional existence is pure speculation. (b) "Utility Fog" is Clarkean Magic, you can do anything as fast as you want with magic. (c) You're dealing with gods... more magic that can do whatever it wants as fast as it wants. (d) Which makes everything you're asking about just opinion. Not even opinion. It's just guessing. BTW: You're asking two questions on a site that allows one and only one question and I have no idea what "plausible" and "possible" mean in this context.

Comment: Please let me make a point about this Stack. We can answer the question, "Given the following well-defined rules of my world and the accompanying example of their use, are the rules believable?" Believable. Not plausible, realistic, or possible, all of which make the assumption that the idea can factually exist. That's not why we're here. But, better still! We love questions like, "I want godlike utility fog to build planets. I'm stuck with how they'd do that in the following detailed and specific way. Can you help me develop my rules?"

Comment: "Can my omnipotent X do Y?" *By definition*, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Enough dust and gas can already assemble itself into forming a planet or even a star, under the drive of gravitational force and without any intelligence in it.

Even if you added the complexity of nanobots/utility fog, you would still face the same problem, that is shedding all the potential energy of the assembled dust which turns into heat. And if the utility fog made the process faster, it would also made the heat fiercer.

But maybe you can use that in your story.

Answer (score 1):

**Nanobots work by Magic**

Any question like "Is it possible for nanobots to do X" the answer is Yes. They can do whatever you like because they work by magic.

In order to ask interesting questions, you must set limits on what your nanobots can and cannot do.

This opens the possibility to build an interesting world, where there is one big handwave at the start, but then you try to manage the consequences according to real world laws.

Answer (score 0):

### Better to work with pre-existing planets

The limitations of a utility fog are a matter of personal preference; so, I cant say for sure IF it could make a planet in this way, but I can logically deduce that even if it could, it probably wouldn't.

Take any random galaxy like our own, and you can assume you have somewhere on the order of a trillion ready to go planets already sitting around waiting to be molded to your gods' will.  Due to the amount to time and energy involved in accreting an entire planet out of cosmic dust scattered across an unfathomably large area, it's probably better to just skip that step and expend the relatively tiny amount of energy it takes to fly to the closest random ball of boring rocks and stuff.

Your gods can still make all manner of logic defying worlds starting from a mundane one, but it's a lot easier to reform Mt Everest into a giant statue of yourself than it is to gather all the dust from the practical vacuum of space to make it from scratch.